# Keeping Derived Class Properties in a Collection

Tags: c#, class, derived

I am in need of assistance, since I am stuck on a problem I have encountered. I have a **List**, `List<Items> ItemList` and I want to put some **ContainerItems** into that list, but when I do, all of the **ContainerItems** properties are gone and it turns into the baseclass of **Items**

```
class Items
{
    public Items()
    {

    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int durability { get; set; }
}
class ContainerItems : Item
{
    public ContainersItem()
    {

    }
    public int maxItems { get; set; }
    public List<Items> ContainItems { get; set;}
}
```

Ideally I would like store all of the Items I'm making into a `Dictionary<string,Items>`.  Is there anyway to store all the **Items** and **ContainerItems** together and keep their properties? thanks in advance!

Comment: Yoo do have their properties, but you need to cast them to `ContainerItems` when you use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have your list of Items:

```
public List<Items> ContainItems { get; set }
```

And now you want to loop through them, but safely as not all of the members of the list will be a `ContainerItems` object:

```
foreach(var item in ContainItems)
{
    if(item is ContainerItems)
    {
        var containerItems = (ContainerItems)item;
    }
    else
    {
        //Otherwise deal with it as an Items object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have either (1) define your list as `List<ContainersItem>` or (2) cast the content of your list in `ContainersItem` each time you want to use fields or functions specific to this class